# php Error Reporting Clarificartion (exact method, syntax & location)

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

Have been researching php error code for an for a quite a while now and there appears to be a conflict:  error_reporting() appears to be both a method and property.  But how can this be? What am I missing?

I've seen references to multiple uses an applications:

```
1a) error_reporting(E_ALL);
1b)error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
1c)error_reporting(0);
```

Okay, so can use integer for true or false(1,0), got it.
Various types of errors or all types of errors (E_ALL [constants]), got it.
All php method so far - got it.

2) But where do you put the code? I can't even tell in php.net
Is in config.php? or is httpd.config? or is php.ini? .htaccess?

3) And what's this [ error_reporting = ~E_ALL] & error_reporting = 0 ]
Is it now a property?

4) What Works for Sure:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

This is great! you can add this code (or similar) to your script and override any default settings for that particular page... and equally clear is display_errors. Just stick it in php.ini (or .user.ini with display_errors=On|Off) -- works every time.

So QUESTION: Where do you put the error_reporting code? and is it a property as well as a method?

Just want to be clear for technical purposes.
Thanks guys

Comment: "error_reporting() appears to be both a method and property." neither, its a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two separate things.

There is a **configuration property** called `error_reporting` that you define in your `php.ini` file. This will be the default value.

There is *also* a **function** called `error_reporting()` that you can use in your application to **override** the default value from `php.ini`.

Comment: Guys, may be irregular comment but is there a way to say thanks.  I know you guru types don't need it but is there way acknowledge the tekkie? maybe  a button we can click on,  a two-thumbs up or something.  I'm new to this and still getting  familiar with the process.